# Why .get() method in Label doesnt work in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi im trying to build a notification app with python and Tkinter, i want to access the text of a Label from my function with .get() but it seems not to work.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
from plyer import notification

gui = Tk()
gui.geometry('500x500')
gui.title('Notifier App')

def createNotification():
    if titleEntry != '' and messageText != '' and whenToDisplayEntry != '':
        get_title = titleEntry.get()
        get_message = messageText.get()
        get_time = int(float(whenToDisplayEntry.get()))
        messagebox.showinfo('Notification', 'Successfully created a notification!')
        time.sleep(get_time * 60)
        notification.notify(title=get_title, message=get_message, timeoout=10)

    else:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Must fill all fields.')

bigLogo = Label(gui, text = 'Make a notification', font = ('Arial', 30)).place(x = 150,y = 1)
title = Label(gui,text='Title of notification:',font=('Arial', 15)).place(x=1,y=100)
titleEntry = Entry(gui, width='20',font=('Arial', 15)).place(x=170,y=100)
message = Label(gui,text='Message:',font=('Arial', 15)).place(x=1,y=150)
messageText = Text(gui, width='20',height='7',font=('Arial', 15)).place(x=95,y=150)
whenToDisplay = Label(gui,text='When to display(in minutes):', font=('Arial', 15)).place(x=1,y=350)
whenToDisplayEntry = Entry(gui, width='10',font=('Arial', 15)).place(x=255,y=350)
createButton = Button(gui,text='Create a notification!',command=createNotification).place(x=180,y=450)

gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please, always add the traceback of the error message.

Comment: @Demi-Lune the error: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.2\Projects\main.py", line 12, in createNotification
    get_title = titleEntry.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: I mean, add the Error in your question (it is unreadable in comments). And also, the Traceback gives you all the info you need to find the error.

Comment: See this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name to get more information on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

By chaining:

```
x = Entry(...).place(...)
```

`x` takes the return value of the function `place`, which is None.

Split your command in  2 lines:

```
titleEntry = Entry(gui, width='20',font=('Arial', 15))
titleEntry.place(x=170,y=100)
```